# making a basic multiplication program in python

Tags: python, input, python-2.7

The goal of the program is for it to multiply two random numbers less than 12 and for the user to guess the answer.  So far i have this . . .

```
import random

g=0
while g<10:
    variable_1 = random.randint (0,13)
    variable_2 = random.randint (0,13)

    answer = variable_1 * variable_2
    guess = input("What is 'variable_1' x 'variable_2'?")

    if guess == answer:
        print "Correct!"
    else:
        print "Incorrect!"
```

The problem is the input box literally says "What is Variable_1 x Variable_2?". But, i want it to have the value of the variables in the input box.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: `randrange(12)` to select `0 <= x < 12`. Your code also selects 12, 13 erroniously

Comment: You don't increment `g`. Is this program supposed to loop infinitely?

Answer (score 6):

Try this instead:

```
guess = input("What is %d x %d?" % (variable_1, variable_2))
```

Comment: I don't think %i means anything. %d means decimal integer. The list of available types is at http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#formatspec

Comment: use `int(raw_input(...))` instead of `input()`

Comment: @Maria: It does. You aren't using the `format()` syntax you linked to, which was introduced in Python 2.6, but the [older string formatting](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/typesseq-strings.html) syntax, in which `%i` is a 'signed integer decimal'. So is `%d`, but IMO that letter is more easily confused with 'double' or 'decimal'. I guess it's a matter of preference.

Answer (score 1):

```
querystr="What is "+str(variable_1)+" x "+str(variable_2)+"?";
```

Then you can

```
guess=input(querystr);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from random import randint

def val(lo=1, hi=12):
    return randint(lo, hi)

def main():
    right = 0
    reps = 10
    for rep in range(reps):
        v1, v2 = val(), val()
        target = v1 * v2

        guess = int(raw_input("What is {} * {}?".format(v1, v2)))

        if guess==target:
            print("Very good!")
            right += 1
        else:
            print("Sorry - it was {}".format(target))

    print("You got {} / {} correct.".format(right, reps))
```